# downloadHandler does not work well with Shiny.onInputChange()

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am building a web tool using Shiny Server.R and try to add a functionality to download csv file. Because the tool is currently built with html and javascript instead of ui.R, I am running the such function to pass in user input dynamically to server to generate the content of csv file.

in .html

```
<a id="downloadData" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm shiny-download-link shiny-bound-output" style="display:inline" target="_blank" href="session/54a5a35f2aee8049087730a3d6e46c33/download/downloadData?w="><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download</a>
```

in .js file

```
Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", JSON.stringify(itemList));
```

in server.R

```
output$downloadData = downloadHandler(

      filename = paste("filename",format(Sys.Date(),"%Y%m%d"),"csv",sep="."),
      content = function(file){
        print(input$mydata)
        write.csv(input$mydata,file,row.names=FALSE)
      }
)
```

By click Download button, it does generate a csv file but the content (input$mydata) is always based on the previous input.

for example, when first load the page and set itemList to 1 and click the Download button, it doesn't generate any file but says error with NULL on a separate page.

**example of error message:**
*unable to find an inherited method for function ‘fromJSON’ for signature ‘"NULL", "missing"’*

Then if i update itemList to 2 and click the Download button again, server.R generates a csv file but when i open the file, it contains 1 instead of 2.

I tried alternate approach as below as well. When below codes are triggered, i do see the up-to-date input$mydata and itemList on my console, but when it reaches to output$downloadData, these values are not being updated but generate a file with previous value..

```
observe({
      if(!is.null(input$mydata)){
        isolate({
        itemList <- fromJSON(input$mydata)
        itemList <- lapply(itemList, function(x) {
            x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
            unlist(x)
          })
        itemList <- do.call("rbind", itemList)
        print(input$mydata)
        print(itemList)
        itemList <- as.data.frame(itemList, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

          filename = paste("filename",format(Sys.Date(),"%Y%m%d"),"csv",sep="."),
          content = function(file){
            write.table(itemList,file,sep=",",row.names=FALSE)
        })
      })
}})
```

Has anyone seen such issue while using downloadHandler with onInputChange()?

Please let me know.

Thanks you!